¿Como correr un script de python en SSH?
soy principiante en programación etc. Como puedo correr un script de Python "Main.py" desde el programa PuTTy - SSH
Por lo cual estoy controlando un invernadero y por necesidades necesito monitorearlo por medio de SSH "HUMEDAD Y TEMPERATURA"
B - HUMEDAD
import rpi.gpio as gpio
import time
# set our gtpio numbering to bcm
gpio.setmode (gpio.board)
channel = 11
relay1 = 16
gpio.setup (channel, gpio.in)
gpio.setup (realay1, gpio.out)
# función para obtener el valor del pin digital
def medirhumedad():
    valor = v.input (11)
    if valor == 0:
        pirnt (“húmedo”)
        gpio.output(relay1,0)
    else:
        print (“seco”)
        gpio.output(realy1, 1)
print (“censando humedad”)
medirHumedad ()
return

TEMPERATURA
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import rpi.gpio as gpio
def temp():
gpio.setmode(gpio.board)
gpio.setwarnings (false)

relay2= 22
gpio.setup (realay2, gpio.out)
while true:
    sensor = adafruit_DHT.DHT11
    pin = 4
    humedad, temperatura = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
if humedad is not none and temperatura is not none and temperatura >= 21:
    print(“Temperatura: ´, temperatura, ´”C”)
    print(“Humedad: ´, humedad, ´%´)
    print(“se abre la ventana y mantiene extractor´”)
    import servo2
    servo2-abrir()
    Relay = 22
gpio.setmode(gpio.board)
gpio.setup(relay2, gpio.out)
gpio.output(releay2, 0)

if humedad is not none and temperatura is not none and temperatura >= 21:
    print(“Temperatura: ´, temperatura, ´”C”)
    print(“Humedad: ´, humedad, ´%´)
    print(“se enciende el extractor´”)
    import servo2
    servo2-abrir()
    Relay = 22
gpio.setmode(gpio.board)
gpio.setup(relay2, gpio.out)
gpio.output(releay2, 0)

if humedad is not none and temperatura is not none and temperatura >= 15:
    print(“Temperatura: ´, temperatura, ´”C”)
    print(“Humedad: ´, humedad, ´%´)
    print(“se cierra la ventana´”)
    import servo2
    servo2-abrir()
    Relay = 22
gpio.setmode(gpio.board)
gpio.setup(relay2, gpio.out)
gpio.output(releay2, 1)

Con el "Main.py" controla los dos archivos, por lo cual  requiero saber como puedo ejecutar el "main.py" desde el "SSH" o por separado imprimiendo los resultados cada 15 min

Asi: "python programa.py". No importa como te conectes al Raspberry Pi; sea vía SSH, telnet o cualquier otro medio, los comandos se ejecutan igual. Si lo que quieres es echar a correr el programa, desconectarte y que siga corriendo, usa el comando screen de Linux. Con él puedes desconectarte y reconectarse sin perder la sesión que tienes abierta. Eso entendi es tu problema; aclara si es el problema es otro.

Hay otras alternativas, como configurar el programa como un servicio en systemd.

También puedes usar crontab para correrlo cada 15 sin que nadie necesite conectarse.
